# Can someone define or explain the ABSTRACT role category in WAI-ARIA?

Tags: wai-aria

The W3C categorizes WAI-ARIA roles into four groups:

- Abstract Roles
- Widget Roles
- Document Structure Roles
- Landmark Roles

Can someone explain the Abstract Roles category?

Answer (score 5):

It does say in the spec:

> Abstract roles are the foundation upon which all other WAI-ARIA roles
>   are built. Content authors MUST NOT use abstract roles because they
>   are not implemented in the API

Essentially, they are a behind-the-scenes thing, and the useful roles (widget, document, landmark) inherit properties from the abstract roles.

If you look at the [taxonomy diagram](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/img/rdf_model.png), the abstract roles are at the top of the tree, and other roles inherit from those.